# Wamp | How to hide queries below webpage?

Tags: php, cakephp

Im a newbie to Wamp and php & mysql. Below the webpage I can see all queries which were executed. How do I hide this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The debug information can be controlled in `app/config/core.php` if you're using Cakephp. Just turn off the debug mode as below:

```
Configure::write('debug',0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to comment the following  code `echo $this->element('sql_dump');` in your default page at `view/layouts/default.ctp`